# Xaml TabControl in the top of window

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, prism, tabcontrol

Hi All!

I have a trouble with `xaml-markup` design that is shown on a picture. How to place window buttons in one line with tab item headers `TAB1`, `TAB2`, `TAB3`?

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/59774606/so_question_pic.png]

I use custom control for window buttons like:

```
<Border>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        ... buttons ...
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Does anyone have ideas how I can implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to remove the window border and draw the buttons yourself. You'll have to handle button clicks yourself (don't forget that maximize is also restore when the window is maximized) and also handle window dragging yourself too!

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"  
        Title="" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"        
        >
    <Grid>
        <Grid Background="Silver">
            <TabControl>
                <TabItem Header="Tab 1"/>
                <TabItem Header="Tab 2"/>
                <TabItem Header="Tab 3"/>                
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Button Content="_" Width="30" Command="{Binding MinimizeCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="-" Width="30" Command="{Binding MaximizeCommand}" />
            <Button Content="x" Width="30" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The commands that you can see hooked up to the buttons are defined in code behind in the window.

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ICommand CloseCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CloseCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CloseCommandProperty, value); }
        }
        public ICommand MinimizeCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(MinimizeCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MinimizeCommandProperty, value); }
        }
        public ICommand MaximizeCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(MaximizeCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MaximizeCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CloseCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimizeCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MinimizeCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximizeCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MaximizeCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            System.Windows.Interactivity.EventObserver a;


            // Setup the commands.
            CloseCommand = new RoutedCommand("CloseCommand", typeof(MainWindow));
            MinimizeCommand = new RoutedCommand("MinimizeCommand", typeof(MainWindow));
            MaximizeCommand = new RoutedCommand("MaximizeCommand", typeof(MainWindow));

            // Put them in the windows command bindings.
            this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(CloseCommand, new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler((s, e) => this.Close()), new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler((s, e) => { e.CanExecute = true; })));
            this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(MinimizeCommand, new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler((s, e) => this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized), new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler((s, e) => { e.CanExecute = true; })));
            this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(MaximizeCommand, new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler((s, e) => this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized), new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler((s, e) => { e.CanExecute = true; })));
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                DragMove();

            base.OnMouseMove(e);
        }
}
```

Comment: +1, although I would use Click events instead of Commands to handle the window management code because its simpler :)

Comment: Easier until you start to look at mvvm and the code behind has no idea what the UI looks like.

Comment: You're fine using code-behind in MVVM providing its code for the UI only, and there's no business/application logic in it. I would consider manipulating the window to be UI-specific, so it's fine putting that in the code-behind when using MVVM :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a now defunct project from Microsoft called the [WPF Shell Integration library](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell), which lets you draw fancy glass windows in WPF, with tabs that go into the title bar area. Unfortunately, it doesn't work perfectly.

The Microsoft Ribbon for WPF SDK has the most up to date version included in it. This is how the RibbonWindow is able to merge the ribbon into the title bar area, like Office does.

Comment: I'm trying to use this, but the link is no longer working