# How can I add a tab control on to the window title bar

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I want to add the tab control header (or styled list box) to the windows title bar like this:

[New window title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fuffi.jpg)

I plan to edit the window template to achieve this. But I don't know where to add. Here is the window template I edit in Blend:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="WindowTemplateKey" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <Grid>
                <AdornerDecorator>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </AdornerDecorator>
                <ResizeGrip x:Name="WindowResizeGrip" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsTabStop="false" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip"/>
                    <Condition Property="WindowState" Value="Normal"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="WindowResizeGrip" Value="Visible"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="WindowStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <AdornerDecorator>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </AdornerDecorator>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource WindowTemplateKey}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Check this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359518/xaml-tabcontrol-in-the-top-of-window

Comment: I knew this. Use WindowStyle="None", then create the Min/Max/close buttons. I want to know whether I can edit the window template to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if I don't want to handle the buttons and dragging myself, I have to use a third party control(such as Actiprosoftware). It handles everything for me, and at the same time, provides a more extendable template.

Comment: It's a trial though.