# Custom Title Bar Buttons in WPF

Tags: wpf, titlebar, window-chrome

I'm completely new to WPF, and am currently learning how to use styles and templates. Today, I saw many projects that can tweak the title bar of the window. Most of them probably tweaked the window chrome to achieve that effect. However, I'm trying to create a title bar with Mac-like Close, Minimize and Maximize buttons. I want them rounded with 3-D Colored effects. I have scoured the internet for that style, but in vain. Could anyone tell me how to achieve that effect using WPF with VB.Net?

P.S. I am using VS2010, and don't have MS Blend.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106943/how-can-i-add-a-tab-control-on-to-the-window-title-bar

Comment: Sorry. That wasn't what I was looking for.